# Как "вытянуть" из char символ

Tags: java, char

Доброго времени суток, подскажите как из Char вытянуть символ, к примеру я хочу из

```
char x = '+';
char a = 1;
char b = 3;
System.out.println(a + x + b);
```

Как делать чтобы считало? Такое ощущение что складывается что-то другое.

Comment: если вы хотите, "чтобы считало", то используйте числовые переменные, а не символы. Скажем, замените char на int

Comment: А как передать какую операцию применить? Если допустим человек вводит 2, потом +, и 3, каждое число считывается и заносится в переменную, а вот как плюс вытащить, чтобы именно знак плюс был не смог найти.

Comment: Плюс и другие символы матопераций можно использовать, как указал в ответе @Free_ze

Comment: Я уже понял, просто хотел узнать для общего развития, что-то есть ещё? Или только в число можно преобразовать char и в код собственно символа.

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону [ScriptEngine][1] - [пример использования][2].


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577259/can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-math-operation-in-java

Comment: Спасибо, интересно) Ради интереса буду и так и так реализовывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
static public int calculate(char op, int first, int second)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        // ...
        case '+':
            return first + second;
        // ...
    }
}

// где-то там
int first = 3;
int second = 2;
char operator = '+';

int result = calculate(operator, first, second);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, можно и так, а ещё есть способы?

Comment: @steelhouse

Как я уже упоминал, напрямую строка в операцию не транслируется никаким образом (можно вызывать компилятор на ходу, но это изврат). Возможно, вам поможет Java Reflection API и его класс Method для выбора необходимого метода на ходу.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Answer (score 0):

Так код символа '+' 43, вот и получаете в ответе 47.

Comment: Ну это я понял, как сделать чтобы + был +, просто я не могу понять. Может там не char использоваться, а что чёрт его знает. Не дошёл ещё видимо до этого.

Comment: @steelhouse
Java - не скриптовой язык, строка в операцию напрямую не превращается, т.е. аналога eval() из javascript здесь нет (хотя, средствами reflection можно найти метод по имени и вызвать его).

Comment: Спасибо, я просто новичёк, спрашиваю, может что-то упускаю.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения числового значения из переменной типа char:

```
    char a = '1';
    int int_a = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a));
```